# What is the current way to grab user pic with Facebook Javascript SDK - best shortcut?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

This is my first time working with the FB JS SDK. I have been looking for the best way to grab a user pic but I am finding all kinds of different methods, some outdated.

I have finally managed to do it by examining the returned object.  But it seems so clunky and long.

```
profileDiv.innerHTML += '<img src="' + response.picture.data.url + '">';
```

Is their a better way to do this?

Comment: what is happening? is that valid URL for the pic?

Comment: It is.. but I was just  wondering if this was the "best" way.  It seems longer than most of the other solutions I had seen, so I thought there might be better options.

Comment: i think you are micro optimizing at this point http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/01/micro-optimization-and-meatballs.html

Comment: Fair enough, but *no* other solution that I saw used a 4-level deep object.  So I just thought I'd check once up-front to see if I was going down the wrong road.

Answer (score 3):

All you really need to display someones profile picture is their `user_id` or `username`.

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/4/picture" width="50">`
```

[image]

Or

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/zuck/picture" width="50">
```

[image]

Using this URL `https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/picture` you can get at the profile picture for that user. You can also specify the size with the `type` parameter. Eg - `type=large`

Comment: This was kind of what I'm looking for I guess, but I am generating the img URL dynamically (the pic appears on the first login and is added by jQuery).  So it looks like if I wanted to generate one of "your" urls I would use ....  ...  profileDiv.innerHTML += "<img src=\"https://graph.facebook.com/" + response.authResponse.userID + "/picture\" />"; .... .... ?  I guess that's the way forward.